# jQuery Ajax sometimes Performs GET Instead of POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery in a MVC application. It looks like the ajax calls work fine in production (I can't reproduce this bug) but I found in the error logs that ajax requests sometimes perform GET instead of POST.

Can someone please explain why this happens? Thanks!

Here is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: "/search/location/cities",
    data: "state=CA",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (cities) {
        //show the cities
    }
});
```

Here is error log:

```
RequestedUrl=/search/location/cities
Http method=GET
Unhandled Exception Occured
A public action method 'cities' was not found on controller
```

Comment: If all the code you have is this one in the question (I doubt it), it should never perform a `GET` instead of a `POST`.

Comment: What error logs are you looking at?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code because what you have now is perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe this get is not done by ajax but by entering url in browser? You should add this information to your logger to be sure.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this question, but did you find the solution? I'm running into this with jQuery 1.12.4 on FireFox 24. Not sure if it's a jQuery issue or a browser issue (FF24 is quite old, but I have no choice). I'm also seeing random GETs in Firebug even though I'm only using $.post. Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

Very much a shot in the dark as there isn't much code to go off of.

```
data:{
    state:"CA"
}
```